# Jquery mobile How to add a defualt value to a filter in list view?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I need to add a default value to a filter in Jquery mobile 1.3.0.
But the example below do not work.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-autodividers="false" data-filter="true" data-inset="true" id="listviewID">                
    <?php foreach($countryList as $country): ?>
        <li value="<?php echo trim(country); ?>"><a href="#"><?php echo trim(country); ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>      
</ul>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ui-input-text.ui-body-c").val('Canada');
    $('#listviewID').listview('refresh');
});
```

Comment: Can you update to jQM 1.4.5 ?

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing the `listview` wont work, as it has already been rendered. The hack is modifying the `input` and firing an `change` event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#listviewID").prev("form").find("input[data-type=search]").val('Canada').trigger("change");
});
```

Note that the selector looks for the inmediate previous form (automatically created by jQM when you specify `filterable`) and the input with `[data-type=search]`, thats more specific than `.ui-input-text.ui-body-c`.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mzsqdfak/2/)**